# Apache NetBeans 12.3 and XAMPP 3.2.4 PHP Breakpoints Windows 10

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xdebug

I spent a few days configuring the Apache NetBeans 12.3 and XAMPP 3.2.4  and PHP and I am not able to make it functional in way, that I will be able to debug the code with a breakpoints working.

1. I installed first new xampp make sure that is completely new installation.
2. Restart of pc needed so I did so.
3. Installed ApacheNetbeans 12.3 IDE
4. Checked the PHP.ini - first strange point. No [Xdebug] Were stated here.
5. I created new project in netbeans put phpinfo() inside run the page , page showed , copied the content , put it to setup wizard downloaded the dll , put dll to the certain place where they stated opened the php.ini ...

5.1 In php.ini no Xdebug was stated so at the end of the file I added [XDebug] and stated part of code.

5.2 I set up the port to 9000  (also 9001 in another attempt) and saved the php.ini with new values in.
6. Stopped the Apache, Stopped the mysql , turned off the Xampp , run xampp under admin rights , started the apache ,and started the mysql
7. NetBeans - opened the project, removed the phpinfo();

7.1 Added the lines: echo("Test"); $x = 1; echo("after Test");

7.2 Added breakpoint on $x=1;
Run in debug mode.

No breakpoint were catched. In netbeans there was a still message that stated: "Waiting for connection ..."

I am not sure what is here wrong , but I checked many other topics ( they are older than this one) and no solution worked. Is it still Apache netbeans and Xampp on windows 10 compatible ?
I know I was able to run and use it few years ago when it was not Apache NetBeans but just netbeans and I did not face that issue. Just installed both Xampp and Netbeans and no other special configuration were needed.

I turned off the firewall ,
checked if there is no zend tags in php.ini ,
checked if it installed it shows it is , and it is OK (shows versions) ,
changed ports to 9001 or different as was suggested in another threads ,
tested few different commands like xdebug.enable_remote  = on , instead 1 and vice versa ...
after I clicked netbeans help which appears after  I stopped debugging the link goes to not found page ...

I googled the wiki page of netbeans and proceed these steps as well  ...
Did anyone face the same issue on clean install ? What is the solution for that or what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks so much .

Edit 17.5.2021 .
There is no antivirus installed and also windows firewall and defender is off .
Localhost can be loaded with page but no break points available.

Edit: Adding my log:

```
Xdebug installed: 3.0.4
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes
Compiler: MS VC15
Architecture: x64
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.4.10
Zend API nr: 320190902
PHP API nr: 20190902
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
OPcache Loaded: no
Configuration File Path: no value
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
```

Comment: 1) Show your Xdebug config 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and then check the log -- it should tell where Xdebug tires to connect t (if it tries at all) and what the response is.

Comment: @LazyOne - can you tell which Xdebug config ? location of file or how to find it ?  Thank you

Comment: Xdebug config. Usually you will put it into php.ini. https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings Just show whole Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 12.3 and XAMPP 3.2.4 are compatible with win10.but if you pre installed antivirus software like avast or  kaspaskey they will detect  xampp   as a malicious software.so before you run xampp turn off the antivirus software and try again.

[First right click on your my computer icon & choose manage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtQ26.png)
[then go to services and applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAfzc.png)

[select services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBizW.png)

[set windows defender startup type to manual instead of Automatic & restart the computer.and try again from installation xampp. you should try from xampp installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpEr6.png)

If it does not work install a xampp old version and try again.
Sometimes windows defender detect it as a malicious software. So turn it off and try again.
There is no matter with netbeans ide.

If you getting problems with xampp every time install zend server or another WAMP software and continue work

Comment: Good point! I will add it to my question. No antivirus is installed . Defender is off.

Comment: Off defender not only windows settings but also you should off the defender service

Comment: Thank you Sandeepa Samaranayake ! Could you please write closely what or how I can put down all the defender service ? I tried the firewall stuff but it still complains "No connection from xdebug was detected " .... Would be really thankful ! - I also added the log I have now . is it OK or there is something wrong with it ? Could you tell please ?